# Vue.js 2 does not update child when in hidden state

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a page which renders a child component (chart) that is passed the data that fills the chart as a prop (list). It is being shown and hidden by a div that wraps it, and my problem is that when it is shown and my data (list) changes, it will properly redraw and update. But if it is hidden while the data changes, and then shown again, NOTHING draws at all in the space, it is blank, not even the previous chart. It looks roughly like this:

```
<div class="bluecards">
  <div v-on:click="isShowpie = !isShowpie">
    My clickable bar title that hides/shows Pie below
  </div>
  <div v-show="isShowpie"  class="content">
    <div class="chartwrapper">
      <pie-chart v-if="loaded" :list="list" class="pchart"></pie-chart>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Does it react differently if you use v-if instead of v-show? Using v-show will create the element at page load even if isShowpie is false, but v-if will only create the element once isShowpie becomes true.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I just changed it to v-if and it DOES redraw now when expanded, but the data is not updated. BUT, I suspect this may have something to do with a thing I need to do to re-render my chart on the sub component, I will look into it further.

Comment: Yep, that was the key, thanks! After slightly modifying the child, it will now redraw when shown. If you want to put your answer in below, I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: glad I could help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v-show` creates the element at page load even if the condition is false(it creates it as hidden). You could try using `v-if` instead as it will only create the element once the condition becomes true.